# Change scale of histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram

My histogram has only one bin in it. How can I convert it in a way such that it has more bins?

I would like to convert graph 2 in the attached image to something resembling graph 1, such that I see more bins.[image]

**EDIT :**

Upon doing `hist(df$FutureCost,main="Multicare Distribution of charges", xlab="Charge($)",breaks="FD",xlim=c(0,500000))`, I was able to get a better graph. Thanks to the replies. How can I convert the numbers 1e+05, 2e+05 etc to numbers like 100000, 200000 etc. 
[image]

Comment: use `hist(x,breaks=number of bars you want)`

Comment: else if you're using `ggplot` then use `geom_histogram(binwidth=your bin width)`

Comment: `hist(x, breaks="FD")` usually finds the right number of bins. Or consider logarithmic scale(s)?

Comment: If you don't want to see values of x that are greater than 500000, then subset your data `hist(x[x < 5e5], breaks = "FD")`. Or adjust the x limits using `xlim`. Maybe take a look at the help page `?hist`.

Comment: @Gregor, I just found that. thank you. hist(df$FutureCost,main="Multicare Distribution of charges", xlab="Charge($)",breaks="FD",xlim=c(0,500000))

But my values in y axis look like 1e+05, 2e+05. Can I convert this to numeric like 100000,200000 etc?

Comment: `options(scipen=100)` ?

Comment: @BenBolker,, thanks. Just one more question. Why is the shading gone in my last graph? Can I get it like my graph1 which is shaded in gray?

Answer (score 3):

A complete (but not reproducible/testable) solution based on the comments above, with some attempt to reproduce the ggplot style ...

```
opar <- options(scipen=100)
par(bg="gray")       ## set plot background color
hist(df$FutureCost,
     main="Multicare Distribution of charges",
     xlab="Charge($)",
     breaks="FD",
     xlim=c(0,500000),col="black")
grid(col="white") ## plots on top of histogram; re-plot
                  ## histogram if you like ...
par(opar) ## restore original settings
```