# How do I aggregate values for a continuous histogram in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to build a histogram with an x-axis beyond -20 and 20. The values range from -25 to more than 25, with more than 6 decimal points, e.g 1.222245, 1.2459809. The current histogram I plot looks like this, which omit values beyond -20 and 20:

[image: Current histogram]

The code is this:

```
  df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=differences)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.3, fill="#69b3a2", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.9) + 
  labs(x = "Difference between Fitted and Observed") + 
  ggtitle("3 Minutes Model") +
  xlim(-20, 20) + 
  aes(y=stat(count)/sum(stat(count))) + 
  labs(x = "Difference between Fitted and Observed", y = "Percentage") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

It returns the message: Removed 30 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).

While I am interested to focus on -20 and 20, there are values beyond -20 and 20 which I do not want to neglect. Instead, I would like to aggregate them as two new categorical variables known as "< -20" and "> 20" so that the histogram accounts for the values beyond what I am focusing on.

It may be possible to transform the values into factors and then produce the histogram. However, if I am not wrong, doing this may require me to rearrange the factors myself, which may be inaccurate and tedious.

Are there any suggestions for this?

Edit:

I think it may be helpful to draw what I am thinking of:

[Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg9Jf.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change scale of histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378955/change-scale-of-histogram-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expand your limits by one extra bin on either side, you can use `scales::oob_squish()` to move out-of-bounds values to the nearest limit.
Example with dummy data below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10000, sd = 10))

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(-21, 21, by = 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-21, 21),
                     oob = scales::oob_squish)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks! It's close enough but I would like the "<-20" and "> 20" to appear like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg9Jf.png

Comment: You can set the breaks and labels manually in the `scale_x_continuous()`. For example:  `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-21, 21), oob = scales::oob_squish, breaks = c(-20.5, -10, 0, 10, 20.5), labels = c("<-20", "-10", "0", "10", ">20"))`. (pardon the formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually force the data outside some cutoffs to be set to the cutoff with a minor modification of your code along the lines of:

```
  df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=pmax(pmin(differences,20),-20))) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.3, fill="#69b3a2", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.9) + 
  labs(x = "Difference between Fitted and Observed") + 
  ggtitle("3 Minutes Model") +
  xlim(-20, 20) + 
  aes(y=stat(count)/sum(stat(count))) + 
  labs(x = "Difference between Fitted and Observed", y = "Percentage") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: Thanks! But the thing is, this doesn't tell me how many per cent of my data is beyond -20 and 20...

Comment: @adrian Data beyond 20 will be shown in the column for 20, do you need some additional indication of which are 'true 20s' and which are 'more than 20s'?

Comment: Hmm its more like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg9Jf.png